# Scrollable VBox with buttons ipythonwidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to create a `scrollable` `VBox` filled with a list of `Buttons`. However I've tried to no avail.

```
import ipywidgets as ipw

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display


vbox = widgets.VBox(layout=widgets.Layout(height='100px', overflow_y='scroll'))


num_buttons = 20
button_list = [widgets.Button(description=f'Button {i+1}') for i in range(num_buttons)]

for button in button_list:
    vbox.children += (button,)


display(vbox)
```

[image: result of code]

I set the `overflow_y='scroll'` and also used the `'auto'` command instead of making the `VBox` scrollable its simply `"squishes"` my buttons

Comment: frankly, it looks like it doesn't display text on buttons. Maybe it has problem with fonts?

Comment: did you tried without `height='100px'`?

Comment: why not `vbox.children += tuple(button_list)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it automatically resizes all widgets to fit them inside `VBox`
and `Button` needs `min_height` to keep some size.

(It doesn't work for `height`)

```
widgets.Button(
    description=f'Button {i+1}', 
    layout=widgets.Layout(min_height='30px')
)
```

---

Full working code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

vbox = widgets.VBox(layout=widgets.Layout(height='100px', overflow_y='scroll'))

num_buttons = 20

button_list = [
    widgets.Button(description=f'Button {i+1}', layout=widgets.Layout(min_height='30px'))
    for i in range(num_buttons)
]

vbox.children += tuple(button_list)

display(vbox)
```

---

`Chrome`

[image]

`Firefox`

[image]

Comment: It works thanks alot !